# Is there ever a situation where one would absolutely need a class component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Is there ever a case where one would absolutely *have to* use a class component, instead of a function component with hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a very small number of rare situations that only class components support at the moment. As the [Hooks FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html) puts it:

> Our goal is for Hooks to cover all use cases for classes as soon as possible. There are no Hook equivalents to the uncommon [`getSnapshotBeforeUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#getsnapshotbeforeupdate), [`getDerivedStateFromError`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromerror) and [`componentDidCatch`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidcatch) lifecycles yet, but we plan to add them soon.

It is very unusual for a script-writer to need those, though not completely impossible. Odds are high that every situation you encounter will be achievable using functional components.

Answer (score 1):

They are necessary when you need to call the child's component methods from the parent via a ref. Programmatic scrolling is a common place where this is necessary. See [React Native ScollView](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview)